# convert text timestamp into correct date and time in google sheets

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I have this text timestamp in a google sheets cell and I want to convert it into a correct date time format that google sheets recognizes, while changing the order of year-month-day to day-month-year and adding +1 hour to it with the 24hr format.

From "TEXT formatted" > `2020-02-08 19:00:12`

To "DATE-TIME formatted" > `08-02-2020 20:00:12`

Could you please suggest a formula?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=TEXT(A1+1/24; "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

---

or you can just do:

```
=A1+1/24
```

and then format it as you wish internally like:

[image: 0]

Comment: Doesn't work since "2020-02-08 17:23:49" is not recognized a number.
Correct syntax should be: ""2020/02/08 17.23.49".

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @Mauriziotis as @player0 suggested, adjust a format to your needs, like `=TEXT(A14+1/24, "yyyy/mm/dd hh.mm.ss")`

Comment: and how to do it with AM/PM?

Comment: @LuizAngioletti https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP2e0.png